# Calling vcvars from bash script

Tags: visual-studio, bash, batch-file

I need to call vcvars32.bat and vcvars64.bat from within the same bash script (msys) which builds different version of my application.

The problem is that, even if I am able to call the batch files with the cmd.exe command, once it returns the Visual Studio variables are obviously not set.

I cannot call vcvars from an external batch file (like msys.bat) which call the bash script, as I need in the same script to call both of them sequentially.

So, is there any way to call vcvars in order to properly set the variables in the bash script while running?

Comment: The only way seems to be to generate a new .sh file that contains the code to set the variables. This is the way it is done [here](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~erikj/build-infra5/webrev.01/common/bin/extractvcvars.sh.html). It was written for cygwin, but it looks like it could be used from msys as well, with some minor changes.

Comment: Which program needs the variables? Another batch file or windows executable? Then you could bundle the vcvars*.bat with that in a batch file

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this is to run your commands from within the vcvars environment, rather than trying to export it back to the bash side. That's the approach we've chosen for our project.

The main problem is that `vcvars*.bat` doesn't accept commands to execute in the environment, so a little bit of trickery with cmd is required. So I came up with a simple Bash script called `vcvars_env_run.sh` that accepts arbitrary arguments and forwards them to a cmd.exe on which `vcvars64.bat` has been called. The bulk of the work is figuring out how to properly forward quoted arguments, and things like &&, ||, return codes, etc.

I've uploaded the script and some examples at https://github.com/kromain/wsl-utils

You might need to tweak it a little to switch between `vcvars32.bat` and `vcvars64.bat`, but hopefully it helps for what you're trying to do.

Comment: But with this method do you have to wait for the `vcvars*` scripts to run for every call?  On my system it takes a few annoying seconds each time. :-/

Comment: Indeed, that is a downside of this approach, you have to wait for vcvars itself to source, which takes an annoyingly long time. I'm hoping they can improve on that in future releases. Even better would be if they provided an equivalent script for WSL environments. I've voiced this request to a couple of WSL project managers, let's see if anything will happen.

Answer (score 0):

The POSIX shell `export -p` prints the values of all environment variables such that an `eval` of the output recreates those values.  The idea is to invoke this from a subshell after `vcvars*.bat` has run and to `eval` the captured output in the top-level script.

A Cygwin environment variable setup script can obtain the results of `vcvars*.bat` as follows:

```
eval "$($(cygpath "$COMSPEC") /c vcvars_export "$vcvars_bat" "$(
                cygpath -w "$SHELL")")"
```

where `vcvars_bat` contains the path of the relevant `vcvars*.bat` file.  You will find this value e.g. in the target of the `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019.lnk` file, which can be read with `readlink -t`.  (Note also that the `vcvarsall.bat` script allows specification of the compiler and SDK version to use, useful when precise control is needed).

The local `vcvars_export.bat` file contains

```
@echo off
call %1 > nul
"%2" -c "export -p"
```

Limitations of the Cygwin native process invocation subsystem (argument quoting is done heuristically) make this auxiliary file necessary.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is to use the command: "call" in your batch script. So it could look something like:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
echo DevEnvDir set to: %DevEnvDir%
```

If you don't use the "call" then the script will exit after the vcvars32.bat exits and won't run any other command.

Comment: No, it doesn't work from bash. I just replicated in bash the environment variables set from vcvars.

Comment: The question applies to bash scripting not Windows scripting.